# Cholesky decomposition in Python using forward and backward substitution functions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need two codes using the ones I have already written for forward and backwards substitution for Cholesky decomposition and to solve with the Cholesky factor. I'm using Python and numpy and need to use the bordered form of Cholesky factorization. I'd like to use the matrix  `A=np.array([(4,0),(0,9)])` for this example if possible. Here's what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np     
from copy import copy


G=np.array([(3,4),(2,5)])
b=np.array([1,2])

def forward_subs(G,b):
    x=[]
    for i in range(len(b)):
        x.append(b[i])
        for j in range(i):
            x[i]=x[i]-(G[i][j]*x[j])
        x[i]=x[i]/G[i][i]
    return(x)

ans=forward_subs(G,b)
print (ans)



G=np.array([(3,4),(2,5)])
b=np.array([1,2])

def back_subs(G,b):
    n=b.size
    x=np.zeros_like(b)
    if G[n-1, n-1] == 0:
        raise ValueError
    x[n-1]=b[n-1]/G[n-1, n-1]
    C=np.zeros((n,n))
    for i in range(n-2, -1, -1):
        bb=0
        for j in range (i+1, n):
            bb += G[i, j]*x[j]

        C[i, i]=b[i] - bb
        x[i]=C[i, i]/G[i, i]
    return(x)

ans=back_subs(G,b)
print (ans)




# define a function
# name : cholesky factor
# inputs : A (2D numpy array) that is positive definite
# output : R (2d numpy array) the Cholesky factor of A
# note 1 : the function should work for square matrices of any size 
# note 2 : use the bordered form of Cholesky decomposition
# note 3 : call the forward substitution function to solve the triangular
#           system in each step (except possibly the first 2) 

def cholesky_factor(A):
     # add code here

    return R

# define a function
# name : solve_system_cholesky
# inputs : R (2D numpy array) that is a Cholesky factor, b (1d numpy array)
# output : x (1d numpy array) 
# note 1 : the function should work for square matrices of any size 
# note 2 : the function should solve the equation Ax=b where
#           the Cholesky factor R of A is provided
# note 3 : call the forward subs and back subs functions to solve


def solve_system_cholesky(R,b):

    # add code here

    return x
```